# Telegram бот не присылает сообщение

Tags: python, linux, telegram-bot, python-3.8

Вот отрывок из кода:

```py
def mssql_conn(message):
    if message.text == "Состояние ремонта":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Введите ID ремонта в формате XX-XXX-XXX")
    else:
        result = re.findall(r'^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$', message.text)
        if not result:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Неправильно введен ID ремонта")
        else:
            cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password+';TrustServerCertificate=yes;')
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT LastStatus,Tovar FROM dbo.b2b_remont WHERE Document_ID = 'result'")
            response = str(', '.join(cursor.fetchall()))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, response)
```

Если отдельно выполнить запрос, и вывести на экран то возвращается значение:
Выдано, наименование товара.

А при отправке сообщения в телеграмм ошибка:

```
2023-01-02 10:42:26,589 (__init__.py:1083 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty"
2023-01-02 10:42:26,590 (__init__.py:1085 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 156, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 100, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 6308, in     run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "/bot/bot.py", line 45, in mssql_conn
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(', '.join(cursor.fetchall())))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1549, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 264, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 162, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 189, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что база данных вернула пустой ответ. Телеграм не позволяет посылку пустых сообщений => он видит пустой текст и выкидывает вам ошибку!

Comment: Я же говорил, если выполнить запрос отдельно, то ответ приходит не пустой.

Comment: Походу я понял в чём проблема, не передаётся  значение в переменную result в запросе: cursor.execute("SELECT LastStatus,Tovar FROM dbo.b2b_remont WHERE Document_ID = 'result'") Нужно правильно расставить ковычки.

Comment: Получается, все заработало?)

Comment: Да, переписал запрос: ("SELECT LastStatus,Tovar,Contact_Mobile FROM dbo.b2b_remont WHERE Document_ID = ?", (result))

Comment: Прекрасно, рад за вас! Успехов!